# Can't access JSON property from itunes api

Tags: javascript, json

I have searched but don't know exactly how to word this and couldn't find an answer.  When I use iTunes' Search API, I'm able to get a response with data but I can't access the properties (`artist`, `album`, `year`, etc).

Also, in the dev tools, when I `console.log` the response, the text is all black. I'm new to API's (and coding in general) but on all other API's when I `console.log` the response, it is formatted with blue and red.

Can anyone help me to access a property? Specifically, I'm looking to get `previewUrl`.

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if this isn't an appropriate question.

Example of my code and the response below.

```
$("#submit-button").on("click", function() {
      let songName = $("#song-search").val();
      var queryURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + songName + "&limit=2";

      console.log(songName);
      $.ajax({
          url: queryURL,
          method: "GET"
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            let preview = response.results.previewUrl;

            console.log(response);
            console.log(preview);
```

And the response:

```
{
  "resultCount": 2,
  "results": [{
        "wrapperType": "track",
        "kind": "song",
        "artistId": 32940,
        "collectionId": 269572838,
        "trackId": 269573364,
        "artistName": "Michael Jackson",
        "collectionName": "Thriller",
        "trackName": "Billie Jean",
        "collectionCensoredName": "Thriller",
        "trackCensoredName": "Billie Jean",
        "artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/michael-jackson/32940?uo=4",
        "collectionViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/billie-jean/269572838?i=269573364&uo=4",
        "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/billie-jean/269572838?i=269573364&uo=4",
        "previewUrl": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview19/v4/41/cb/e3/41cbe381-2991-071b-7985-76afbbabab6a/mzaf_5021382539648526963.plus.aac.p.m4a",
        ...
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you're accessing a JSON object and not just a string (in which case you'll have to call [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)) `results` is an array, so you'd access the `previewURL` for the first result like this:

```
var url = response.results[0].previewUrl
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  response.results[0].previewUrl doesn't work.  I think you're on to something with JSON.parse thought.  If i go to the api request url in chrome, it actually downloads a .txt file so maybe it's not actually json?  I'm going to try to parse it.  should just be JSON.parse(results) right?

Comment: @dmoss215 what happens when you try my solution? Some error about `.results` being undefined? in that case assign `var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response)` and do the `.results....` on the `jsonResponse`.

Comment: got it! you were right. it needed to be parsed.  so i created a variable to store the result of JSON.parse(response) and now i can access everything.  and var url = newResponse.results[0].previewUrl works to get the preview.  Thanks so much! been at this one for hours.

Comment: No problem @dmoss215. Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?